# Reading space-separated numbers from cin in C++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I have to put the numbers from each line of input into different vectors without knowing how many numbers there will be in one line of input. For example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 -7
```

should result in

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6, -7};
```

Note that the number of integers in each line is unknown.

I've tried using `stringstream` but for some reason it didn't work for two lines of input:

```
int main() {
  vector<int> a, b;

  string c;
  int number;
  stringstream lineOfInput;

  getline(cin, c);
  lineOfInput.str(c);
  c = "";

  while (lineOfInput >> number) {
    a.push_back(number);
  }

  getline(cin, c);
  lineOfInput.str(c);
  c = "";

  while (lineOfInput >> number) {
    b.push_back(number);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The first vector is filled normally, but the second doesn't. Is there a good way to extract numbers from lines (without using boost library) and what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Call `lineOfInput.clear()` between the first and second line. The stream still has eof bit set.

Comment: The code has two blocks that do the same thing: parse numbers from a string and push each number into a vector. That sounds like a function: `std::vector<int> parse(const std::string& input)`. Construct an `istringstream` object (note: not `stringstream`, which is overkill, since it does output as well as input), and extract values from the string. Voila: problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use lineOfInput as a condition in a while loop it will run until it enters the fail state, so the second while with the same stringstream will never run because it doesn't return true. Just add `lineOfInput.clear()` and everything will be all right.

Also when you run into a problem like this it's helpful to debug and see what really happens.